# Sort by field values from 2 columns - mysql - delphi - dbgrid

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, sql-order-by, dbgrid

I have two columns named `priority` and `state`:

- The column `priority` will only contain field values: `urgent` and `normal`.
- The column `state` will only contain field values: `wait`, `executed` and `done`.

I'm trying to sort these using my `dataset CommandText` property, so the `dbgrid` connected to the dataset displays the data in the sort order I've set there.

The sort order should be like this:

1. 1. Rows containing `urgent` in the `priority` column should start the DBGrid list.
   2. Then the list should continue with the ones marked as `normal` in the `priority` column,
2. 1. followed by the ones marked as `wait` in the `state` column,
   2. followed by the ones marked as `executed` in the `state` column,
   3. and finally the list ends with the ones marked as `done` in the `state` column.

I can't figure out how to write the SQL statement for this, so I can use it in the `CommantText` property for the dataset.

I am using this currently:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
  ORDER BY FIELD(column_name, "normal", "urgent") DESC
```

This works with the first column `priority` but doesn't take into account the second column `state`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close.  You just need a second key in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY FIELD(priority, 'urgent', 'normal'),
         FIELD(state, 'wait', 'executed', 'done')
```

Notes:

- I removed the `DESC` from the first key.  You are using `field()`, so put things in the right order.
- This will order the "urgent" by the same three keys.  This seems consistent with your question.

Comment: Figured that would work, but as I'm rather new to this I was adding another ORDER BY in front of the 2nd FIELD, guess it's the little things, haha. Thank you for your answer and the extra clarification regarding DESC, that makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: I also have a table named ID set to auto increment, primary and Unique. Could that interfere with this sort in any way? I've just tried and it does work but they're upside down (urgent to bottom and normal at top) in my dbgrid

Comment: Are you sure, you don't still have the `DESC` in your query?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann Yes, I'm sure, just double checked - this was happening with the old sort by 1 column also, that's why I added the DESC, that seemed to clear things up - although not entirely.

Comment: https://s16.postimg.org/g9pahw5p1/Capture.png - I figure these 2 columns to be the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: What let you conclude these columns to be causing the problem? BTW, don't add important information in comments. Rather, edit your question.